# Need design suggestion for storing data for budget keeping application

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I'm writing an application that I will use to keep up with my monthly budget. This will be a C# .NET 4.0 Winforms application.

Essentially my budget will be a matrix of data if you look at it visually. The columns are the "dates" at which that budget item will be spent. For example, I have 1 column for every Friday in the month. The Y axis is the name of the budget item (Car payment, house payment, eating out, etc). There are also categories, which are used to group the budget item names that are similar. For example, a category called "Housing" would have budget items called Mortgage, Rent, Electricity, Home Insurance, etc.

I need a good way to store this data from a code design perspective. Basically I've thought of two approaches:

One, I can have a "BudgetItem" class that has a "Category", "Value", and "Date". I would have a linear list of these items and each time I wanted to find a value by either date or category, I iterate this list in some form or fashion to find the value. I could probably use LINQ for this.

Second, I could use a 2D array which is indexed first by column (date) and second by row. I'd have to maintain categories and budget item names in a separate list and join the data together when I do my lookups somehow.

What is the best way to store this data in code? I'm leaning more towards the first solution but I wanted to see what you guys think. Later on when I implement my data persistence, I want to be able to persist this data to SQL server *OR* to an XML file (one file per monthly budget).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your first attempt looks nicer, obviusly the second could be faster (depends on how you implement it). However when we are talking about desktop applications which are not performance critical, your first idea is definitely better, expecially because will help you a lot talking about maintaining your code. Also remember that the entity framework could be really nice in this situation

Finally if you know how to works with XML, I think is really better for this type of project. A database is required only when you have a fair amount of tables, as you explained you will only have 2 tables (budgetitem and category), I don't think you need a database for such a simple thing